# How to remove chapter heading's large top margin?

Tags: sectioning, margins

I am trying to implement a simple chapter heading for my document but can't find an appropriate solution to my desired format as shown in the image below. I want to have a chapter heading which is centered, has the same font size as the content but boldface, and have **no top margins**. The default chapter headings are absurdly large. What's the simplest way to do this?

[image]

Comment: try having a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins

Answer (score 2):

This is a recurrent question, but nobody wonder why expert typographers chose a  default layout with a lot of space before a chapter title.

Said that, `memoir` have several predefined chapter styles, some without a extra space at top, and one (`thatcher`)  similar to the screenshot, so a simple solution could be use this class and just type:

```
\chapterstyle{thatcher}
```

The MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)

[image]

`\section`s and `\subsection`s can also be formatted this way.

EDIT. The negative space `-24pt` is selected by trial and error. If you change line spread, let's say from `[doublesapcing]` to `[singlespacing]`, you will have to adjust this length, probably around `-12pt`. This is why `showframe` is added for a reference.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\centering\normalfont\bfseries}
    {Chapter \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\centering\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-24pt}{*0}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```